# open csv as utf8 without creating a query

Tags: csv, microsoft-excel-365

I often need to open utf-8 encoded csv files in Excel (365).

I open them using Power Query (get data - from text/csv) where I can specify encoding, and it's generally fine.

However sometimes I need to share those files and it takes me an extra step to remove queries from the file. Is there any way to open csv with utf-8 encoding without creating a query?